# Почему не переносится текст?

Tags: html, css, текст

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  border: solid red;
}

nav ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  
  position: relative;
  
  list-style: none;
  border: solid green;
}

nav ul li {
  padding: 1em;
  border: solid yellow;
}

nav ul li:hover ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

nav ul li ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  
}

nav ul li ul:hover {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>
      dropdown 1
      <ul>
        <li>bla 1 bllllllllllllllllllfffffffffffffdddddddddddddddlllllllllllllllllll kkkkkkkkla</li>
        <li>bla blbla</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    
    <li>
      dropdown 2
      <ul>
        <li>blabla 2 bla</li>
        <li>bla blablablablablagggggghghrhrtggggggggaaaaaaaaaaaaaabla blabla bla</li>
       </ul>
    </li>
    
    <li>
      dropdown 3
      <ul>
        <li>3 bla</li>
        <li>bla blabla blabla bla</li>
       </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что одно слово. Добавь это:

```css
word-break: break-word;
word-wrap: break-word;
overflow-wrap: break-word;
```